# Continuous-time Markov chain and mutually exclusive states

Tags: markov-chains, exponential-distribution

Let's say we have a 3-state Markov chain $X_t \in \{S_0,S_1,S_2\}$ with $X_0 = S_0$ and with $S_1$ and $S_2$ being absorbing states.  Let $T_1 \sim Exp(\lambda_1)$ and $T_2 \sim Exp(\lambda_2)$ be independent exponentially distributed RVs representing times for moving from $S_0$ to $S_1$ and from $S_0$ to $S_2$ respectively.  Then we have

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_t = S_0) = \exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t) = \exp(-\lambda_1 t)\exp(-\lambda_2 t) = \mathbb{P}(T_1 >t)\mathbb{P}(T_2 >t)
\\
 \mathbb{P}(X_t = S_1) = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} - \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}\exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t)
\\
\mathbb{P}(X_t = S_2) = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} - \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}\exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t)
\tag{1}\label{1}
$$

But on the other hand we also have, if I understand it correctly,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_t = S_1) = \mathbb{P}(T_1 \le t)
\\
\mathbb{P}(X_t = S_2) = \mathbb{P}(T_2 \le t)
\\
\mathbb{P}(X_t = S_1 \cap X_t = S_2) = \mathbb{P}(T_1 \le t \cap T_2 \le t) = \mathbb{P}(T_1 \le t)\mathbb{P}(T_2 \le t)
\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

but the last expression should be zero as the states are mutually exclusive.

So, we have mutually exclusive states, but they are related to independent exponential RVs. How do we reconcile the two: mutual exclusivity and independence?

**Add 1**

Following @Ian's answer, it looks like instead in $\eqref{2}$ we have

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_t = S_1) = \mathbb{P}(T_1 \le t \cap T_1 < T_2) 
= \int_0^t \lambda_1 \exp(-\lambda_1 t_1) \int_{t_1}^{\infty} \lambda_2 \exp(-\lambda_2 t_2) \mathrm{d}t_2 \mathrm{d}t_1 
= \int_0^t \lambda_1 \exp(-\lambda_1 t_1)\exp(-\lambda_2 t_1)\mathrm{d}t_1
$$

which does indeed agree with the $\eqref{1}$

**Add 2**

If we observe the process at time $t_0 > 0$ and find that $X(t_0) = S_0$ and we want to calculate the probability that the process will be in state $S_1$ at some time $t_1 > t_0$, do we normalize the above by the "remaining" probability of being in state $S_0$ at $t_0$?  That is, does the expression become

$$
\mathbb{P}(X(t_1) = S_1 | X(t_0) = S_0) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(t_0 < T_1 \le t_1 \cap T_1 < T_2)}{\mathbb{P}(t_0 < T_1 \cap t_0 < T_2)}  \; \; ?
$$

And is the denominator given by

$$
\mathbb{P}(t_0 < T_1 \cap t_0 < T_2) = \int_{t_0}^{\infty} \lambda_1 \exp(-\lambda_1 t_1) \mathrm{d}t_1 \int_{t_0}^{\infty} \lambda_2 \exp(-\lambda_2 t_2) \mathrm{d}t_2  = \mathbb{P}(t_0 < T_1)\mathbb{P}(t_0 < T_2)  \; \; ?
$$

If yes, then again it seems like there is a conflict: if the times $T_1$ and $T_2$ are independent, then how can we guarantee that the states are mutually exclusive?  Can't both $T_1$ and $T_2$ turn out to be the same? Or does the fact that the times are continuous means that $P(T_1 =T_2) = 0$? What if we measured time in, say, days - could we still model transitions with discrete distributions of time (say, both $T_1$ and $T_2$ follow geometric distributions) and how would we handle $P(T_1 =T_2)$ in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is that the process stops running once $t$ reaches $\min \{ T_1,T_2 \}$, and so $P(X_t=S_1 \wedge X_t=S_2)=0$ as you would expect. The actual situation is $P(X_t=S_1)=P(T_1<T_2 \wedge \min \{ T_1,T_2 \} \leq t)$ and analogous for $S_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I do understand that the process stops running once one of the events takes place, so there is no misunderstanding there, I don't think.  The thing I was confused with is how to express the joint probability of being in the two absorbing states in term of the exponential RVs.  From your answer, it looks like we can write $P(X_t=S_1) = P(T_1 < T_2 \cap T_1 \le t)$ - is this correct?

Comment: @Confounded That's the same as what I wrote, yes.

Comment: This ability to model mutually exclusive Markov states in "competing exponentials" framework seems to depend on the condition that only one of the events can happen at any time, which in turn seems to depend on the distribution of times being continuous which means that $P(T_1 = T_0) = 0$.  What if our times have marginal discrete distributions (say, measured in days)  - can we still use this framework and how do we handle the possibility of two events happening at the same time now?  Thank you

Comment: @Confounded If the model is continuous time Markov and time-homogeneous then the only possibilities for holding time distributions are memoryless, which forces exponential holding times. If it's discrete time Markov and time-homogeneous then you have geometric holding times instead. If you drop time homogeneity then you can get other holding time distributions.

Comment: (Cont.) Anyway, your actual question is a modeling matter. Math can't really tell you how to deal with it by itself. For example, you could introduce a fourth state, and then you need to decide whether you can reach this state from $S_1$ and/or $S_2$.

Comment: No sure I follow. In continuous time, the process jumps to the state for which the exponential time is the first one, e.g. it jumps from $S_0$ to $S_1$ if $T_1 < T_2$. Because the times are continuous, $P(T_1 = T_2) = 0$ and hence only one state is selected. But in discrete time we can have $P(T_1 = T_2) > 0$ and so it's not clear how a state is picked in this case. Thank you.

Comment: Really $T_1,T_2$ isn't the right way to think about it at all. You generate $T$ based on the sum of the rates, and then you pick a state to go to based on the ratio of the rates.

Comment: Again, not sure I follow. I am sure I have read that continuous time MC is modelled as "competing exponential" with the first exponential time determines the next state. Is this not correct?

Comment: @Confounded You *can* model it that way, but it's a clumsy way to think about it, especially in the time-homogeneous case. The fact that the analogous setup doesn't work in DTMCs (because of ambiguity in selecting the next state) helps with seeing this. The jump chain/holding time model is much better at least in the time-homogeneous case.

Comment: "You generate T based on the sum of the rates, and then you pick a state to go to based on the ratio of the rates."  Do you mean that we use something like a categorical distribution to select the state?  It seem to me that thinking about competing processes is helpful (and feels more natural to me) in certain cases, rather than splitting the whole thing into holding times and state selection.

Comment: @Confounded This way is faster numerically in the time-homogeneous case and IME is more natural analytically also. The other way has weird dangling issues, like what is the meaning of $T_2$ when the process actually went to $S_1$?

Comment: But isn't infinitesimal generator $Q$ only "works" within competing processes view?

Comment: Not really, no. Keep in mind that the analysis is looking at the movement of probability between states in the entire ensemble, while the trajectory generation (which is what you're handling in the OP) is just looking at one trajectory at a time. There isn't really any reason for these to be done in the same framework. Also note that in a DTMC there is no reason to use holding times at all other than computational performance, because you just get the probability at the next time step immediately.

Comment: Maybe it's because I am dealing with time-inhomogeneous case that I find it more useful to think about the problem in terms of competing processes.  Anyway, thank you for your insight.  PS.  May I ask you to look at another post of mine on the subject here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4193287/markov-chain-probability-of-getting-to-one-of-the-states-before-another ? Thank you

Comment: In the time-inhomogeneous case you end up needing to discretize time normally anyway, unless you can exactly sample from the holding time distribution.