# Markov chain: probability of getting to one of the states before another

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, infinitesimals, transition-matrix

Let's say we have a 3-state CTMC represented by
$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{ccc}   
 &  & \Large{\enclose{circle}{1}} 
\\\
 & \lambda_1 \Large{\nearrow} & 
\\\  
\Large{\enclose{circle}{0}} & & \Large{\downarrow} \lambda_2
\\\
& \lambda_2 \large{\searrow} & & 
\\\
 &  & \Large{\enclose{circle}{2}} 
\end{array} 
$$

where the time to go from $0$ to $1$ is distributed as $T_1 \sim Exp(\lambda_1)$, and the time to go from $0$ to $2$ and from $1$ to $2$ is $T_2 \sim Exp(\lambda_2)$.

The system starts at $t_0=0$ in state $0$, i.e. $P(X_0=0) = 1$. I am looking to find the probability that the state $2$ is reached before state $1$ within some time interval $\Delta t$ given that $X_t = 0$, i.e.

$$
P(t < T_2 \le t+\Delta t \ \cap \ T_2 < T_1 |X_t = 0) \equiv p_{0,2}(t,t+\Delta t)
$$

I think this can be evaluated as

$$
p_{0,2}(t,t+\Delta t) 
\
= \int_t^{t + \Delta t}\lambda_2\exp(-\lambda_2 t_2) \int_{t_2}^{\infty}\lambda_1\exp(-\lambda_1 t_1) dt_1 dt_2 
\\
= \int_t^{t + \Delta t}\lambda_2\exp(-\lambda_2 t_2) \exp(-\lambda_1 t_2)dt_2 
\\
= \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} \left[\exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t) - \exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)(t + \Delta t)) \right]
$$

Is this correct or do I need to normalize by something since we are NOT at $t=0$ but $X(t) = 0$? Since we have two processes, should the normalizing factor be $P(T_1 > t \cap T_2 > t)$ to give

$$
P(T_2 \le t+\Delta t \ \cap \ T_2 < T_1 | X_t = 0) = \frac{P(t < T_2 \le t+\Delta t \ \cap \ T_2 < T_1)}{P(T_1 > t \cap T_2 > t)} ?
$$

If this is the correct normalization to be applied, then I think we have

$$
P(T_1 > t \cap T_2 > t) = \exp(-\lambda_1 t)\exp(-\lambda_2 t)
$$

which gives

$$
P(T_2 \le t+\Delta t \ \cap \ T_2 < T_1 | X_t = 0) = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} \left[1 - \exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)\Delta t) \right] .
$$

On the other hand, this process, I believe, can be expressed using an infinitesimal generator $\mathbf{Q}$ as

$$
\mathbf{Q} = \pmatrix{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) &\lambda_1 &\lambda_2\\ 0 &-\lambda_2 &\lambda_2\\ 0 &0 &0}
$$

The eigenvalues of this matrix are $\{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2), -\lambda_2, 0\}$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are

$$
\mathbf{V} = \pmatrix{1 &1 &1\\ 0 &1 &1\\ 0 &0 &1}
$$

so the solution of the forward equation, if I am not mistaken, is

$$
\mathbf{P}(t) = \exp(\mathbf{Q}t)
\
= \mathbf{V} \exp\pmatrix{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t &0 &0\\ 0 &-\lambda_2 t &0\\ 0 &0 &0} \mathbf{V}^{-1}
\\
= \mathbf{V} \pmatrix{\exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t) &0 &0\\ 0 &\exp(-\lambda_2 t) &0\\ 0 &0 &1} \mathbf{V}^{-1}
\\
= \pmatrix{1 &1 &1\\ 0 &1 &1\\ 0 &0 &1} \pmatrix{\exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t) &0 &0\\ 0 &\exp(-\lambda_2 t) &0\\ 0 &0 &1} \pmatrix{1 &-1 &0\\ 0 &1 &-1\\ 0 &0 &1}
\\
=\pmatrix{\exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t) &\exp(-\lambda_2 t) - \exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t) &1-\exp(-\lambda_2 t)\\ 0 &\exp(-\lambda_2 t) &1-\exp(-\lambda_2 t)\\ 0 &0 &1}
$$

However it's not clear to me how to extract $p_{0,2}(t,t+\Delta t)$ from this $\mathbf{P}(t)$?

The results for $(\mathbf{P}(t))_{0,2} = 1-\exp(-\lambda_2 t)$ also feels strange to me since it seems to ignore the possibility of getting from $0$ to $2$ via $1$ and so I would have expected there to be $\lambda_1$ terms in it - what is going on here?

I suspect that the issue might be with the way I expressed $\mathbf{Q}$ since I only have two competing exponentials, not 3.  Or do I?  If the mechanism governing transition from $0$ to $2$ and from $1$ to $2$ is the same, do we consider it as one exponential RV or two for the purpose of representing an CTMC?

Comment: You can achieve your desired outcome by just forcing 1 to also be absorbing and then computing $\left ( e^{Q \Delta t} \right )_{0,2}$. This filters out the paths in the original chain that reached $2$ via $1$. Of course one can quickly see without any annoying linear algebra calculation that the answer will be $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$ times the probability of any transition in time $\Delta t$ so $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2) \Delta t}$.

Comment: @Ian  Yes, I got to the same conclusion that setting $1$ to be absorbing simplifies this calculation, but I need to calibrate the model (including the $\lambda_2$ parameter) and it seems to me that for this I need to keep the "full" version.

Comment: I don't understand why. The point is to "count" the paths that go from 0 to 2 directly not via 1. Using a fake process in which 1 is absorbing achieves exactly this. This is precisely how the "committor" (a function which says the probability to go to some set $A$ before some other set $B$ started from each point $x \not \in A \cup B$) is computed. There is no detail in the OP that tells me why this cannot work. Edit the OP if there is such a detail.

Comment: To clarify, I am not saying "forget about the arrow from 1 to 2 for all purposes categorically". I am saying "you can solve this particular question about this model which does have the arrow from 1 to 2 by solving the corresponding problem with the arrow removed".

Comment: @Ian  Thank you.  What about the result $(\mathbf{P}(t))_{0,2} = 1-\exp(-\lambda_2 t)$ ? I would have expected the probability to move from state $0$ to state $2$ to include both paths, i.e. $0 \to 2$ and $0 \to 1 \to 2$, and hence to include $\lambda_1$ in the result, but it doesn't.  What is the explanation for this?  Or have I got my calculations wrong?  Thank you

Comment: Your calculation is wrong for what you wanted to do. But it is right for the actual matter of measuring the probability to be in state 2 after time t, since you can't leave state 2 and the rate of passage into state 2 is the same whether you are in state 0 or state 1.

Comment: "Your calculation is wrong for what you wanted to do."  Could you please elaborate? 
"the rate of passage into state 2 is the same whether you are in state 0 or state 1." But for the second path the process first needs to enter state $1$ from state $0$ before it can then move onto state $2$  - why this doesn't seem to be reflected in the result?

Comment: #1: Your calculation is wrong for what you wanted to do in the OP because it includes the 0 -> 1 -> 2 path that you were trying to exclude. #2: The passage through 1 is not reflected in the result because passing through 1 doesn't change anything about how long it's going to take to get to 2 relative to not passing through 1. It would if the 1->2 arrow had a distinct rate say $\lambda_3$.